# My Ipomea Violacea plants keep their flowers white

Tags: flowers, flowering

Any idea why my Ipomea Violacea flowers remain all white, in deed almost all white: there are sometimes little little diffuse stains of purple at the basis of the corolla.

It should be deep blue/purple.

Not enough sun, fertilizers, pH ?

I thought it was an easy plant to grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ipomea violacea isn't always violet coloured - it comes in white, pink, bi colour and purple, so unless you bought a named variety which specifies the colour, yours just happens to be white with a hint of purple.

Comment: so I will have to check that next year. I wanted them to be deep blue/purple :-)

Comment: Yes, check the colour - sometimes sold as purple I. violacea, I. violacea purpureum, sometimes as I. tricolor, but some confirmation of the colour is necessary.